# Json to Html using bootbox?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting the following JSON value:

```
[{
        "employee_id" : 10,
        "name" : "george"
    }, {
        "employee_id" : 20,
        "name" : "luke"
    }, {
        "employee_id" : 30,
        "name" : "rita"
    }
]
```

I want values to display in a table format in bootbox, I tried the below code but I am not able to generate it.

```
bootbox.confirm(
    '<div style="font-size:15px;" class="accordion-body collapse in lst"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"</i>&nbsp&nbsp<b>Select the Server Size</b><br/><br/>\n\
     <div  class="content"><table style="border-collapse: inherit;" class = "table table-striped" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr><th>Select</th><th class="collapse">Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>'
     for each (var item in obj) {
     '<tr><td><input type="radio" id="server_size" name="server_size" value='+item.id+'><td>'+item.name+'</td></tbody></table></div></div>'
      }
     ,'ok' , 'save');
```

Comment: <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"</i> ??

Comment: Are you trying above code in php or in javascript.

Comment: I am using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try building the content outside then passing it into the function. Do not forget to concatenate the strings:

```
var x = '<div style="font-size:15px;" class="accordion-body collapse in lst">'
      + '<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i>&nbsp&nbsp'
      + '<b>Select the Server Size</b><br/><br/>\n'
      + '<div  class="content"><table style="border-collapse: inherit;" '
      + 'class = "table table-striped" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr>'
      + '<th>Select</th><th class="collapse">Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

for each (var item in obj) {
      x += '<tr><td><input type="radio" id="server_size" name="server_size"'
        +  ' value='+item.id+'><td>'+item.name+'</td></tbody></table></div></div>';
}

bootbox.confirm(x,'ok','save');
```